# The order of two subgroups product is not greater than the product of two subgroup orders $|AB|\le |A|\times|B|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, and let $A,B\le G$ be finite subgroups of $G$.

The product $AB$ is defined as following :

$AB =\{a\times b | a\in A, b\in B\} $

Show that $|AB|\le |A|\times |B|$.

My attempt so far:

Observe that $AB=\bigcup_{a\in A} aB$, and by Lagrange theorem we know that $|aB| = |B|$.

We also know that for any $x,y\in G$ either $xK\cap yK=\emptyset$ or $xK=yK$.

How can I continue from here?

Comment: you have $AB=\bigcup_{a\in A} aB$ and $|aB| = |B|$ and this implies the result you want since the union is of at most $|A|$ cosets

Comment: @DavidHolden I just can't understand why. Is there any simple example I can use to test it ? Like $S_3$?

Comment: You don't need Lagrange or any group structure for this, and you don't need $A,B$ to be subgroups, or finite. Any binary operation and any two sets will work more or less the same (though you do need some of this data to have the equality from Pedro's answer).

Comment: It's completely obvious from the definition of $AB$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show that $|AB||A\cap B|=|A||B|$. There is a map from $A\times B$ to $AB$ that sends $(a,b)\to ab$. This is obviously surjective, which gives away your inequality. Now note that for any $c\in A\cap B$, $(ac,c^{-1}b)$ maps to $ab$. Now supose $(a',b'),(a,b)$ are such that $a'b'=ab$. Then note that $c=a^{-1}a'=bb'^{-1}\in A\cap B$, and $(a',b')=(ac,c^{-1}b)$. Thus any fibre has cardinality $|A\cap B|$.

Recall that if $f:X\to Y$ is any map, we can define an equivalence relation $\sim $ on $X$ by $x\sim y$ whenever $f(x)=f(y)$. The class of an element $x$ is $[x]=f^{-1}((f(x))$, and we can define $\tilde f: \widetilde X\to Y$ by $\tilde f[x]=f(x)$. Then $\tilde f$ is injective, and thus gives a bijection between $\widetilde X$ and $f(X)$. But $X$ has cardinality equal to $n_1+\cdots+n_k$ where $n_i=|[x_i]|$ for $1\leqslant i\leqslant k=|\widetilde X|$ and each $x_i$ is a representative of the classes of $\widetilde X$. If each class has equal cardinality $N$, then $|f(X)|= |\widetilde X|=|X|/N$.

In the above, $N=|A\cap B|$, $|f(X)|=|Y|=|AB|$ and $|C|=|A\times B|=|A||B|$, whence the formula.